# select distinct from several columns

Tags: php, mysql

I've a table of cities, states and zips, but as you know some cities have multiple zip codes.  I want to return one of the city rows, not all associated with all zips.  This is for predictive text input.

```
cities2 Table example
Colorado Springs | CO | 80910 | Colorado Springs, CO
Colorado Springs | CO | 80911
Colorado Springs | CO | 80912

{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `cities2` WHERE `city` LIKE '$city%' LIMIT 5");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    $cities[] = $row['city'];
}
```

I would like to return the first 5 city names that start with "Colo" but only 1 colorado springs.

I hope I explained that well.

Answer (score 0):

you just need a group by

```
SELECT * FROM `cities2` WHERE `city` LIKE '$city%' GROUP BY city LIMIT 5
```

you can group by what ever column you want to be distinct.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
  FROM cities2 
   WHERE city 
    LIKE '$city%' 
      GROUP BY city 
        LIMIT 5
```

Comment: Perfect, forgot about the GROUP BY, was just thinking DISTINCT.

Answer (score 0):

From my soapbox:

1. Only use `GROUP BY` when using aggregate functions. Use `DISTINCT` instead
2. Explicitly state the columns you want returned, not *.
3. Use an `ORDER BY` to ensure consistent results are returned every time the query is executed

My recommendation:

```
SELECT DISTINCT city
FROM cities2
WHERE city like '$city%'
ORDER BY city 
LIMIT 5;
```